# PHP-site - login error

Tags: php

I have been following this series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdZuhlQ88e8&list=WL&index=52. I have followed about 4 of his videoes, but at that point nothing really worked.. So I decided to start all over again, and this time i only got this far:

```
<?php
if($_POST['login'])
{
//get data
$userrname = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 
}

?>

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Brukernavn:<br />
<input type="text" name="username"><p />
Passord:<br />
<input type="password" name="password"><p />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Logg inn">
</form>
```

I got this error, and I can't figure out why.. 
"Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\hotellformidling\ny\login2.php on line 3"

Function:    {main}( )
Location:    ..\login2.php:0

Does anyone have any idea to what I can do? 
Thanks:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first do,

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

to check $_POST data,then do like below

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
```

Answer (score 0):

> form action="login.php" method="POST"

In this line as `action = "logoin.php"`, it will search for a file named `login.php` when you click the `submit` button. But I suppose, you have named your file `login2.php`. Change either one of them, so that there is same name on both the places `[in form action and your file name]`.